# Kerr Black Hole Rendering issues

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

Alright so, i have been working on a very bootleg 3D render engine for Black Holes in Houdini. And i encountered some results which i am not 100 about.

Exibit One;
[image]

This was the first attempt at an implimentation of the Kerr Effect. Now i dont entirly understand what happened with my Event Horizion, but overall it shows the correct behaivor.

Exibit two;
[image]

This is a lot better. But i started to notice an issue. Aside from my Photonsphere just kind of dying, it does not really appear to be correct. In all illustrations of the Kerr Effect i see something like this;

[image]

As in, the Event Horizion stays circular and onyl the Photonsphere moves to one side. Yet here, the entire Event Horizion gets streached. I did read some papers suggesting this might be how it looks. But then on for example Wikipedia, i see this graphic;

[image]

To be fair, in my latter example the Spin is only at -0.5c but still. It is noticable and i wonder if that is correct or an error.

Maybe it is important, so i will quickly explain how the Kerr Effect is achived in my implimentation.
Each light ray is bend using 2 metrics. The first is the Gravitational Pull of the Singularity with an Inverse square falloff. This results in a vector pointing towards the singularity and pulling the Light ray towards it.
Kerr, at its core, is just rotation. So i make a Kerr field which creates rotating Vectors around the Singularity. The final force a light ray is subjected to is equiviliant to the Gravitational Pull + Kerr.
From what i understand, this should be a valid implimentation because, but i could be wrong.

So yeah, is what my render engine produces in any way accurat or not ?

Thanks for any insight :D

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are solving for actual light paths (null geodesic in the Kerr metric) but instead using a heuristic method that ignores the spacetime curvature.

Comment: Pretty sure its actual light rays. Here is a visualisation of a few rays https://imgur.com/gallery/kGvaxRf

Comment: To me it looks like you have the rays progress in flat space, not taking into account that it is actually severely curved. Ideally you should map to something like Boyer–Lindquist coordinates and back to make it physically realistic.